# Calling NSMutableArray:addObject is resulting in an unrecognized selector exception

Tags: objective-c

I'm getting an unrecognized selector exception attempting to call addObject on an array. However my array is an NSMutableArray, not an NSArray. I don't understand why this is happening.

I have the following classes:

```
@interface A : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy)     NSMutableArray* children;
- (id) init;
- (void) addChild: (A*) child;
@end

@interface B : A
- (id) init;
@end

@implementation A
- (id) init 
{ 
   self = [super init];
   return self;
} 

- (void) addChild: (A*) child
{
    [self.children addObject:child];
}
@end


@implementation B
-(id) init 
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
           self.children = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return (self);
}
```

Then if I create an object of type B and call [b addChild: anObject] I'm getting an unrecognized selector and I don't understand why.

The output is:

```
2013-04-08 14:31:08.046 otest[13381:7e03] -[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17759c0
```

What is the problem?

TIA

(Please focus on the actual code and problem, not side discussions why I'm not allocating the array in A's init, unless relevant. I want to understand why the code as it stands does't work. Thanks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By declaring the array with the storage qualifier `copy` instead of `strong`, your mutable array will be copied on assignment and turned into an immutable NSArray.

Comment: Many sources I've red say it is good practice to make mutable items, such as NSMutableString and NSMutableArray copy rather than strong. If that is the case, then what is the solution to getting this to work while also following good practice?

Comment: It's good practice when you want to guard *against mutable assignment*.  In your case, you really want a mutable array, so copy is always the wrong move to make.

Comment: @Mungbeans, here's a blog post that has some suggestions on what you might consider (including writing your own `setter` for example): http://vgable.com/blog/2009/03/17/mutable-property-and-copy-gotcha/

Comment: Making a mutableCopy of a mutable array is the exact same thing as a retain anyhow.  I see no reason to modify any setters or getters to simulate a `mutableCopy`-esque storage qualifier.